# Solving 'commits ahead' with git cherry-pick

Tags: git

I have *main* and *feature* branch in which the latter is two commits ahead of *main*.
[image]
They have this git graph.
[image]

My goal is to bring one commit from the *feature* into *main* so that *feature* is down to one commit ahead, so I used the following commands to import the commit:

```
git checkout main
git cherry-pick 431f303e...
git push
```

After that, the git graph looks like this
[image]

and now *main* has the change from that commit. But I'm not sure why *feature* is still saying that it is two commits ahead of *main*.
[image]

Does anyone know whether there is any additional git command(s) that I'm missing? I'm also wondering if cherry-pick is the correct command to achieve this goal.

Comment: Because it is - you have two commits on your branch that are _not_ in main. Your cherry pick is a _different_ commit, compare the hashes.

Comment: You didn't changed `feature` branch at all and it still has own two commits. Instead cherry-picking (one commit of two) you should perform merge or rebase.

Comment: Thanks folks. 'git rebase' is the answer that I'm seeking.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the source code of Github but I think it looks for merge
base of main and feature (check locally with `git merge-base main feature` command) and notices that there are 2 commits after it
on feature. In git commit id depends on the previous commit so if you
cherry-picked the newest commit from feature to main its id will be
different on main.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Arkadiusz. It looks like git rebase is the answer that I'm looking for.